# Typescript mapping array of different types

Tags: typescript, array-map, union-types

how to avoid union type for each resulting element (needed [valueOfTypeOne, ValueOfTypeTwo] instead of (valueOfTypeOne | ValueOfTypeTwo)[]) in such scenario ?

```js
const [valueOfTypeOne, ValueOfTypeTwo] = await Promise.all(
  [
    fetchTypeOne(),
    fetchTypeTwo(),
  ].map((promise) => promise.catch(() => null)),
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid union type"

Comment: I made an update on the question. plz check

Answer (score 0):

Using `.map()` on a tuple will essentially convert the tuple to an array type and you will lose the type information. See here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6574

One way to fix this is two append the `catch` to each Promise.

```
const [valueOfTypeOne, ValueOfTypeTwo] = await Promise.all(
    [
      fetchTypeOne().catch(() => null),
      fetchTypeTwo().catch(() => null),
    ],
);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=5&pln=7&pc=3#code/FDAmFMGMBsEMCdwAIBmBXAdpALgSwPYarjaQAWAKgJ4AO4A8huABQCUSAXEgArz4C2uAM7gAPEOzxcGAOYA%20MFDiJUmHASIoS5anQoB3fG048%20gkaIxp%20AI3DwFwZrCFUsSYwF45SAN7AkJEhCCSQAbQA3WGg0BhRdBiYAGiQANWjY%20njacAN8AF0kTyRYfVhcbFMBYXAAOmjoZgDA8OaW4lJKHMYWVlrIWE7mLx8raGhWJLaWrU6EvLZ%20wfJh9m8kMYmp9vztpFYAbmAAX1Y2YCA)

Comment: However if there are multiple fetches, you would need to duplicate the `catch` calls, and what if the promises are not hard coded - which is why I think a utility function would be the most canonical solution.

Answer (score 0):

A nice utility function that will do the mapping for us and hide away the type of `map` can do the trick:

```
function catchToNull<P extends Promise<any>[]>(...promises: P): { [K in keyof P]: Promise<Awaited<P[K]> | null> } {
    return promises.map((p) => p.catch(() => null)) as never;
}
```

It iterates through each promise and unwraps it, wrapping it back with `null`.

You would use it like this:

```
const [valueOfTypeOne, valueOfTypeTwo] = await Promise.all(
    catchToNull(
        fetchTypeOne(),
        fetchTypeTwo(),
    )
);
```

And in the case of an array of promises, use spread:

```
catchToNull(...arrayOfPromises);
```

You might find that you need to type the array of promises as a tuple if necessary:

```
catchToNull<[Promise<number>]>(...onlyOnePromiseInThisArray);
```

You can find and try this solution [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMxBsAFgCoCeADiAPIogBc8AFAJTwC8AfPAAoxIC2ASzQgAPCgCufAEYgY7ANwBYAFChIsBMnRZc+YuRBEA7knrM2nHvyGjMMASgDmClSuziUYDANSIoeoiQAOXEICBEueBAADwwQFGA0bl5BYREoFBJ2AG0AXXYGADpishSbNHouJnoAb3hsgGl4B3gAaxASJGxuXMqytIBBIygBOOAIxvz4AB94CTDOAF94GpV4dfg4DHEYFHhS62E0Qr4oMgYGMhYOfcKwf0IL6855iCYWKCSaADdZJWVFq5lAxPiRPIxnis1hstJh6t8oBBxFRsKQKNQQAAaeAIpEotGGEy5NjwKDDUbJQ4gQqIiAMaHrAD0jI26wAegB+BmsvwBYKhOncnkbXSEAkY5iYoXCnB4MUGYxISXS9ZMblMf6LJjMeRAA).